# How to make LLDB pretty print?

Tags: lldb, neovim, codelldb

When I debug a C++ program in Neovim, the variables look like this

[image]

which seems too messy. I expect it to look like this:

[image]

I found LLDB using variable formatting to custom display options for variables. I tried using some scripts, such as:

- [libcxx.py](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/lldb/examples/synthetic/libcxx.py), and
- [gnu_libstdcpp.py](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/lldb/examples/synthetic/gnu_libstdcpp.py)

but these didn't work for me.

Comment: I can't tell what you are objecting to.  In the top display lldb is getting the std::string value right.  I can't tell whether the std::map and std::vector have the `size=N` summary output because the window is cut off.  It seems like you are mainly objecting to the fact that the type is printed before the value?  If so, then that's a choice being made by neovim, and isn't affected by data formatters.  lldb has options to print or not print types, and neovim seems to be choosing the latter.

Comment: latter -> former...

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely! I want lldb not to print types

Comment: lldb isn't the one choosing to show types in this locals display view.  lldb provides printing methods for values that display types and ones that don't display types, and it looks like the neovim-lldb module is choosing to print types.  Maybe neovim offers some way to configure this?  lldb doesn't have a way to say "even though my client asked for types to be printed, don't..."